# Lattices/Topology and the Stone Duality

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, lattice-orders

For some context I have some partial understanding of lattices and an intermediate understanding of topology.

I at some point in the past week started thinking about a funny way to view a topology on a space as constituted by a lattice of open sets. In the sense that a union of two sets corresponds to a join and a intersection to a meet. Then in some sense the axioms of a topology on a space can be translated to a set of axioms on our lattice For example since the space itself and the null set are both open then there exist maximal and minimal elements. Since arbitrary unions of opens are opens then we can take joins of arbitrary number of elements, but since only finite intersections of opens are (gaurenteed to be) open then we can only take meets for finite sets of elements. I see these ideas more or less reflected in the wikipedia page for the stone duality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_duality#The_adjunction_of_Top_and_Loc.

However most resources on this connection are fairly advanced often bringing in a good chunk of category theory. My background in category theory is very limited.

While I understand that a formal treatment of this duality inevitably will involve some construction of some pair of functors between topological spaces and lattices, I was wondering if there was a resource that might give a softer and more intuitive introduction to this area. Or is it simply time to bite the category theory bullet

Furthermore I am interested if there is any work in applying topological notions to the appropriate types of lattices. For example it seems that we can extend notions of homotopy equivalences between spaces to homotopy equivalences between latices. Similarly we can extend compactness quite easily. Furthermore one could also construct algebraic invariants like the homology or fundamental groups of a lattice.

This doesn't seem to hold for all the usual topological concepts since  it seems by switching to lattice one loses the notion of points and thus cannot straightforwardly talk about Hausdorfness, limits etc. Thus it seems one would recover a slightly altered version of the usual topological notions for suitable lattices.

I can find bits and pieces of these ideas scattered across several papers and articles and blogs. Is there any centralized resource focused on this type of stuff?

Comment: Your idea is not fresh: topology is a special case of lattices. It seems that there are few researches about connnecting topology and lattices. The sheaf theory, limit and colimit in categories actually uses topology as lattices implicitly.

Comment: Regardless of this particular topic, I encourage you to explore category theory! "biting the category theory bullet" makes me think you're dreading it, but trust me, it's beautiful. Even if you don't end up liking it, it's a great pedagogical tool: it allows you to notice vast general patterns occurring across many areas of mathematics, so that instead of learning and building intuition for every specific instance, you just have to learn it once. It's like when you first jump from high school maths to abstract algebra. I recommend "Category Theory in Context" by Riehl.

Comment: There are some references at [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53929/locales-and-topology) that you could check out

Comment: It doesn't specifically discuss lattices as far as I can see, but you might be interested in looking at *Topology: A Categorical Approach* by Bradley, Bryson & Terilla. Its aim is to reintroduce the standard concepts you learn in a first course on point-set topology from a categorical perspective, alongside teaching you the category theory. In the opposite direction, ch. 11 of Davey & Priestley, *Introduction to Lattices and Order*, discusses the application of Stone duality to topology.

Comment: Elementary considerations (well below category-theoretic notions) can be found in standard works on lattices and Boolean algebras (e.g. [Sikorski](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3642858228), [Birkhoff](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821810251), [Givant/Halmos](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387402934), [Abbott](https://archive.org/details/setslatticesbool0000unse), etc.). See also Vaidyanathaswamy's [**Set Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486404560) and the original papers by Stone, Frink, Wallman, etc. in the 1930s and 1940s.